# Testing a react component that is wrapped in react hot keys

Tags: reactjs, hotkeys, jestjs

Hi I am quite new to react. I have implemented key board shortcuts in my react application using react-hotkeys.

The plugin basically asks to wrap rendered code inside following tags

```
<Hotkeys>
// Component render output
</Hotkeys>
```

Now how to test this kind of components? I wrote a test case like this

```
it('Shows text passed', () => {
 var expected = [1,2,3,0];
 const wrapper = renderer.create(<HomePageRow title={'Home Row Title'}cards={[]}/>);
 const inst = wrapper.getInstance();
 expect(inst.render()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

It gives following error

```
Console

console.error node_modules\react-test-renderer\cjs\react-test-renderer.development.js:5530
  The above error occurred in the <HotKeys> component:
      in HotKeys (at homePageRow.js:68)
      in HomePageRow (at home.test.js:14)

  Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

What is this error boundary? How to ignore HOCs in testing? Did anyone implement react-hotkeys plugin and wrote tests to your component? If so can you please help me how to write them?

Answer (score 1):

The `WrappedComponent` property of any Component can help you access component wrapped with HOC's without creating a mock for the HOC :

```
it('Shows text passed', () => {
 var expected = [1,2,3,0];
 const wrapper = renderer.create(<HomePageRow.WrappedComponent title={'Home Row Title'}cards={[]}/>);
 const inst = wrapper.getInstance();
 expect(inst.render()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

If it's not a HOC try just to mock `Hotkeys` :

```
jest.mock('../../../Hotkeys', () => (
  jest.fn(() =>
    <div>Hotkeys component</div>,
  )
));
```